# Htaccess redirect urls that match with Regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect any url's that match the following criteria:

```
old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ads/
old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ads/anyhting-after-this-too
old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ads/anyhting-after-this-too/anyhting-after-this-too/
etc...
```

to

```
new-domain.com/deal/
```

This is what my `.htaccess` file looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^marketplace/businesses/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/ads/(.*) http://new-domain.com/deal/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried several variations os this including swapping the `([a-z0-9\-_]+)` with `([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)` and `[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)` and other combos but I can't seem to get it to work.

Also notice where I said `anything-here` in the urls that means I want to be able to match pretty much anything that would be there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A quick test on my local machine confirms that your regex should work for what you're trying to do. I'm wondering if something doesn't like the backslash being used to escape the dash in the first pattern group. Have you tried [-a-z0-9_] or [^/] instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a physical directory at `/marketplace/businesses/` with a `.htaccess` file that was preventing this from working.

I was able to add this to that `.htaccess` file and it worked like a charm.

Thanks to everyone who had a look and took a stab.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work. (Haven't tries it though)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^marketplace/businesses/(.*) http://new-domain.com/deal/$1 [NC]
```

This will translate this

```
old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ads/
old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ads/anyhting-after-this-too
old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ads/anyhting-after-this-too/anyhting-after-this-too/
```

to this

```
http://new-domain.com/deal/anything-here/ads/
http://new-domain.com/deal/anything-here/ads/anyhting-after-this-too
http://new-domain.com/deal/anything-here/ads/anyhting-after-this-too/anyhting-after-this-too/
```

Or like this i you want to keep the parts intact, try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^marketplace/businesses/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/ads/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+) http://new-domain.com/deal/$1/$2 [NC]
```

This will be translated to this

```
http://new-domain.com/deal/anything-here/anyhting-after-this-too
```

but I don't think the other two will match the regexp.

Comment: 1 reason this won't work is because I need to keep old-domain.com/marketplace/businesses/anything-here/ intact because I have a php script that is forwarding those. Also, i'm using 301 redirects.